# Why does my array get reversed despite me not touching it at all?

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, mongodb, express

I am building a website and I have a router, however the problem is not the router, but the calculations inside it, I am making an array `tomato` and after putting what I want in it all the values are okay, however right before I render a page the values of the array apparently get reversed? I am not even touching the values on the other code, here it is:

```
router.get('/reportsNested', function(req,res,next){
  Question.find({
    $expr: {
      $gt: [
        {
          "$size": "$reportsNested"
        },
        0
      ]
    }
  }).sort({reportsNested: -1}).limit(20).exec(function(err,results){
    let tomato = [];
    for(let i =0; i< results.length; i++){
      for(let j =0; j < results[i].reportsNested.length; j++){
        tomato.push(results[i].reportsNested[j]);
      }
    }
    console.log(tomato)
    for(let i =0; i< results.length; i++){
      let reserveranswers = results[i].answers
      let answersArr = []
      for(let j =0; j < results[i].answers.length; j++){
        answersArr.push(results[i].answers[j])
      }
      answersArr = answersArr.sort((a,b) => (a.likes[0]-a.dislikes[0] < b.likes[0]-b.dislikes[0]) ? 1 : ((a.likes[0]-a.dislikes[0] > b.likes[0]-b.dislikes[0]) ? -1 : 0));
      results[i].answers = answersArr;
      let reserveranswersText = [];
      for(let j =0; j < results[i].answers.length; j++){
        reserveranswersText.push(results[i].answers[j].text)
      }
      for(let j =0; j<results[i].reportsNested.length; j++){
        for(let h = 0; h<reserveranswers.length; h++){
          results[i].reportsNested[j].answerIndex = reserveranswersText.indexOf(results[i].reportsNested[j].answerText);
        }
      }
    }
    console.log(tomato)
    res.render('reports', {type: 'nested', user: req.user, reports: results, reporttoremove: tomato})
  })
})
```

when I am console logging tomato array for the first time it outputs:

```
 [
  {
    username: 'SweetWhite',
    answerIndex: 2,
    answerText: `<h2 class="makewrap" style="flex-wrap: wrap; overflow-wrap: break-word; font-family: 'Times New Roman';">me an lemon lemonme an lemon lemonme an lemon lemonme an lemon lemonme an lemon lemonme an lemon lemonme an lemon lemon</h2>`
  },
  {
    username: 'SweetWhite',
    answerIndex: 0,
    answerText: `<h2 class="makewrap" style="flex-wrap: wrap; overflow-wrap: break-word; font-family: 'Times New Roman';">do I become an amongusdo I become an amongusdo I become an amongusdo I become an amongus</h2>`
  }
]
```

And for the second time it outputs tomato it outputs this! :

```
[
  {
    username: 'SweetWhite',
    answerIndex: 0,
    answerText: `<h2 class="makewrap" style="flex-wrap: wrap; overflow-wrap: break-word; font-family: 'Times New Roman';">me an lemon lemonme an lemon lemonme an lemon lemonme an lemon lemonme an lemon lemonme an lemon lemonme an lemon lemon</h2>`
  },
  {
    username: 'SweetWhite',
    answerIndex: 2,
    answerText: `<h2 class="makewrap" style="flex-wrap: wrap; overflow-wrap: break-word; font-family: 'Times New Roman';">do I become an amongusdo I become an amongusdo I become an amongusdo I become an amongus</h2>`
  }
]
```

I have been reading this code for hours and I don't understand why the array is reversed!
Any help would be very appreciated!

Comment: sort is a in-place operation, it mutates original array

Comment: But I am not sorting the tomato array, only the answers array? Why does it affect the tomato array even though I already stored it as a variable and defined it? How can it redefine it? I have been working with JavaScript for a while and never knew JavaScript acts this way! Wow

Answer (score 0):

The reason for the tomato getting reversed is sort updating the reference.

Try doing this.

```
const tomato = [];
for (let i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
  for (let j = 0; j < results[i].reportsNested.length; j++) {
    tomato.push({ ...results[i].reportsNested[j] });
  }
}
```

I tried in my machine and it works.

Comment: @SweetWhite - Did you try like above? object de-construction  would create a duplicate and any changes on results would not pass to tomato.